# CMake autogenerated files missing includes CMAKE_C_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: linux, cmake

I have a complex build I'm trying to sort out on a new build server.  Using CMake for creating the makefiles.  Old version of CMake on a different server was 2.8.5.  New version is 2.8.12.2.  For some reason, the autogenerated CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake files are missing the CMAKE_C_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH, which specify the absolute location of the include headers available to that particular directory.  Without that information, the source code in that directory that references headers via a local path (such as foo.h versus ../../../asdf/foo.h) won't compile.  Any ideas why these are missing?  As far as I can tell this is supposed to be autogenerated by CMake.

Comment: Do you mess different CMake versions? Do you use **internal** CMake variables like `CMAKE_C_INCLUDE_PATH` in **your code**?

Comment: I do not.  But CMake autogenerated files use CMAKE_C_INCLUDE_PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful command that got me further into my build:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE ON)
```

But that didn't actually solve my problem.  The real issue was that in one of my CMakeLists.txt files I had:

```
include_directories(
  $[XXXX_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
```

The '[' bracket was causing the build to fail because that include directory was not being used.  However, on the old build server, it had no issue with this square bracket.